# Why laravel-image-optimizer in Laravel is not working?

Tags: laravel

Hellwo guies.
I need image optimizer but he in nt working. I installed how in instruction, my code in Controller:

```
$pathToImage ='storage/app/aD87ODcVpFc.jpg';
  $pathToOptimizedImage = 'storage/app/aD8.jpg';

   $optimizerChain = OptimizerChainFactory::create();
$optimizerChain->optimize($pathToImage, $pathToOutput);
```

It take image, run throw optimazer, make copy but but this copy r not optimize.
In config/image-optimizer I have this settings:
'optimizers' => [

```
    Jpegoptim::class => [
            '-m85', // set maximum quality to 85%
            '--strip-all',  // this strips out all text information such as comments and EXIF data
            '--all-progressive',  // this will make sure the resulting image is a progressive one
        ],
...
```

How can I get optimize image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Check if you installed laravel-image-optimizer third-party software.

For example for Jpegoptim run - `sudo apt-get install jpegoptim` (if you are using Debian Linux distro) and so one for the others `optimizers` in your image-optimizer.php file.